# What is preventing my ssh connection to mac

Tags: ssh, mac

I am trying to ssh to mac from a windows machine - my user name should evidently be xme when I look at my home icon in finder, so I try `ssh xme@ip` address. the ip address is the one I received via `ipconfig getifaddr en0`

when I do that I get back connection timed out.

then I went and looked at my settings for mac Remote Login

it says Allow Access only for these users

Administrators

which I am in but I decided to try to add my name explicitly, so I found there was user XmeM so I added that and tried again

```
ssh XmeM@ip
```

but same error. What should I be doing to SSH into this mac?

Comment: Did you check macOS's built-in firewall? Did you see if you could ping the Mac's IP address from the Windows PC? Are you sure en0 is the interface by which the Mac is connected to your LAN? Is the Windows box on the same Ethernet/Wi-Fi LAN as the Mac?

Comment: hmm, evidently I am not on the same LAN with the two computers, darn it. So you're right I should have pinged first.